# dispatchKeyEvent contains no metastate

Tags: android

I have implemented an override of `Activity.dispatchKeyEvent` in order to capture certain key presses which I want to handle before they are dispatched to any of the views in my `Activity`, specifically to implement keyboard shortcuts for common actions. The signature looks like this:

`public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`

The trouble is, I am not receiving any `metaState` in my `KeyEvent`, and therefore I have no idea whether the shift key, alt key, Ctrl key, or any other modifier is being applied to the key. It doesn't make sense to me that this is the case, but that's what's happening and I don't understand why. How can I read the modifiers state of the keys I am receiving in `dispatchKeyEvent` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found my error. I was trying to do this with an emulator. When I used a real device with a physical keyboard, it worked exactly as expected. Lesson learned!